# Benefits when using Angular with actions on Google interactive canvas

Tags: angular, actions-on-google

I've recently started looking into the [Interactive Canvas](https://developers.google.com/assistant/interactivecanvas) for Actions on Google.
In the documentation Google [states](https://developers.google.com/assistant/interactivecanvas/build/web-app#architecture) that interactive canvas works with any major front-end framework such as React and Angular. I researched both the frameworks and noticed that Angular is being developed by Google. This made me wonder if there is any benefit to using Angular for the interactive canvas.

I'm only looking for benefits that will help with development for interactive canvas such as integrations with Google products such as Firebase and Google cloud storage. Not general pro's over other front-end frameworks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no inherent advantage to using Angular for the Interactive Canvas over other frameworks. There is nothing in Angular that was specifically designed for IC.

Nor is there an inherent advantage to using Angular to access Google servers.

Although Google does make all of them, Google is a big company, and each team generally builds for a wide base, often unaware of what their own company may offer.